# Kotlin join file content words with single quotes

Tags: kotlin

I have this text in the file, I want to read the combine as string with single quotes.

```
b3
a1
d5
h1
j1
m3
```

I want output like this:

```
 ( 'a1','b3','d5','h1','j1','m3')
```

have this code, but its not producing the output what I need.

```
   val fileName = "c:\\temp\\a.txt"
    val content = File(fileName).readText()
    val lstValues: List<String> = content.split("\\s+").map { it -> it.trim().toLowerCase() }
    val tmmp = lstValues.sorted().distinctBy { it.toLowerCase() }.joinToString{ it -> "\'${it}\'" }
    println(tmmp)
```

giving output like this:

```
'b3
a1
d5
h1
j1
m3'
```

How to generate the output what I expect using Kotlin code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to my low reputation, I can't write a comment. Instead, I post as an answer.

You forgot to use String.toRegex().

```
content.split("\\s+".toRegex()).map { it -> it.trim().toLowerCase() }
```

This will work as you expected.

Comment: This is an answer, so it shouldn't have been a comment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If the input file has one value per line, it's probably more efficient and more idiomatic, as well as simpler, to use [`readLines()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-lines.html) instead of [`readText()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html):

```
val lstValues = File(fileName).readLines()
```

You can then transform the list as in the question, without a separate splitting stage.

(It's usually more efficient to use [`useLines()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/use-lines.html) instead, so that the file can be processed in a stream without reading it all into memory at once.  But there's no benefit here, as you need it all in memory to sort it.)